# Is there a way to use CronJobs in Vaadin Flow similar to Spring Boot serverside?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm looking for a way to implement a CronJob into my Vaadin application similar to the way Spring Boot allows it?

Spring allows me to annotate a method for example with: `@Scheduled(cron = "0 1 1 * * ?")`

I could not find something similar for Vaadin Flow.
How ever I saw that Vaadin apparently has CronJob support? I'm not really sure whether that is a third party package or officially provided by Vaadin since I cant find much about it.

Note that I do not need to send a push notification or such through the CronJob. The CronJob only needs to run serverside within my Vaadin Flow application.

Does Vaadin provide any build in functionality for fulfilling those periodically server side tasks? Or would you recommened to use a third party Java CronJob library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vaadin doesn't have any specific support for scheduled jobs. You can use whichever third party solution you want. In particular, you can use Vaadin together with Spring Boot and thus also have direct access to its integration.

One thing to keep in mind if you're doing something to update Vaadin components from a scheduled job is that you need to enable `@Push` and use the `UI.access()` if you want updates to be pushed out to the user immediately. See [the documentation on server push](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-access.html) for more information.